# Binary relations: Can someone see if I have done this correctly?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, solution-verification

I would appreciate some help.

Here are the binary relations:

Below we are defining some binary relations over the set {a, b, c}

1. *S* ₁: {〈a, a⟩, 〈a, b⟩, 〈b, b⟩, 〈b, c⟩}
2. *S* ₂: {〈a, a⟩, 〈a, b⟩, 〈b, b⟩}
3. *S* ₃: {〈a, a⟩, 〈a, b⟩, 〈b, b⟩, 〈b, c⟩, }
4. *S* ₄: {〈a, a⟩, 〈a, b⟩, 〈b, a⟩, 〈b, b⟩, 〈c, c⟩}
5. *S* ₅: {〈a, a⟩, 〈b, c⟩, 〈c, b⟩}

Here is the questions:

1. Which element(s) is missing in *S* ₁ so it can become a *reflexive* relation?
2. Which element(s) is missing in *S* ₂ so it can become a *symmetric* relation?
3. Which element(s) is missing in *S* ₃ so it can become a *transitive* relation?
4. Which element(s) can you remove from *S* ₄ so it can become anti-symmetric relation?
5. Which element(s) can you remove from *S* ₅ so it can become a irreflexive relation?
6. Which of the binary relations above are *reflexive*?
7. Which of the binary relations above are *symmetric*?
8. Which of the binary relations above are *transitive*?

Here is my answers:

1. We can insert 〈c, c⟩ in *S* ₁ and it will become a *reflexive* relation.
2. We can insert 〈b, c⟩, 〈c, c⟩, 〈a, c⟩, 〈c, a⟩, 〈b, a⟩, 〈c, b⟩ in *S* ₂ and it will become a *symmetric* relation
3. We can insert 〈a, c⟩, 〈c, c⟩ in *S* ₃ and it will become a *transitive* relation
4. We can take out 〈b, a⟩ from *S* ₄ and it will become a *anti-symmetric* relation
5. We can take out 〈a, a⟩ from *S* ₅ and it will become a *irreflexive* relation
6. *S* ₂ is a *reflexive* relation
7. *S* ₄ and *S* ₅ are *symmetric* relations
8. *S* ₂  and *S* ₄ are transitive relations

As you can see, i've figured out all the answers for the tasks, but i'm unsure if the answers are correct. I would appreciate if someone could see if I have done anything wrong here or if there is something i'm missing.

Thanks alot!

Comment: I updated the binary relation part, with the set

Answer (score 2):

In order to check if a relation is reflexive you need to know on which set the relation is defined.
My guess would be that you are meant to use $\{a,b,c\}$ in all cases.
This assumption makes $S_2$ not a reflexive relation, because it is missing $(c,c)$.

Your second answer is correct, but just inserting $(b,a)$ is sufficient.

Your third answer is correct, but just inserting $(b,c)$ is sufficient.

Your sixth answer is wrong, only $S_4$ is reflexive under the assumption mentioned earlier.

The other answers are correct.

Comment: yes, {a,b,c} in all cases, I updated the post now

Comment: thanks for help, but what would first and third relation be then?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but a relation need not be either reflexive or symmetric or transitive or asymmetric or irreflexive.